# Blogger Soho: original alt text is missing in home page

Tags: xml, blogger

Soho theme is not adding the original alt text to the images in home page, instead Soho sets "image" as alt text for all images in home page. On the other hand Awesome Inc theme shows the original alt text for all images on home page. I can't switch to a different theme because I made tons of CSS modifications and I don't want to lose them. Alt text in home page images is too important for me because it's the only thing keeping my website behind competitors in Google search results. I'm not experienced in Blogger themes but I think the following piece of code is what responsible of generating post image in home page in Soho theme.

```
    <b:include data='{ image: data:post.featuredImage,  
                              imageSizes: [280],
                              sourceSizes: &quot;(max-width: 576px) 100vw,
                               (max-width: 1024px) 576px, 490px&quot;                                     
                              }' name='responsiveImage'/>
```